# Java Scanner Changing String

Tags: java, file-io, java.util.scanner

I'm doing some basic file reading from a text file using Scanner.

The first 5 entries are this -

```
 0 MR2Spyder
1 Tundra
3 Echo
3 Yaris
4 ScionxB
4 ScionxD
```

I instantiate the scanner normally and then do this -

```
String line = scanner.nextLine();
System.out.println(line);
```

I then get this output -

```
ÿþ0 M R 2 S p y d e r
```

Which doesn't make sense to me- is there some problem with the Scanner class? Should I be using BufferedReader?

Comment: Looks like you are having encoding issues. Use the Scanner constructor with the correct encoding.

Comment: You're using Unicode file encoding. Specify that.

Answer (score 6):

Your file is encoded using UTF-16... the spaces between characters and the heading `ÿþ` is indicative of that -- it is the [*byte order mark*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-16):

> if the 16-bit units use little-endian order, the sequence of bytes will have `0xFF` followed by `0xFE`. This sequence appears as the ISO-8859-1 characters `ÿþ` in a text display that expects the text to be ISO-8859-1.

You must [specify that when constructing your `Scanner`](http://goo.gl/ZJdxX).

```
final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file, "UTF-16");
```

Comment: @praks5432 since you appear newer here, please don't forget to mark the answer [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) which helped most in solving the problem.