# Input read with Scanner and then printed shows different characters

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am experiencing a problem with Java's Scanner class. When i input a certain sequence of characters i get an even crazier one back with no alterations whatsoever. For example using the code:

---

```
public static void main(String args[]){
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Begin");
   String foo = input.nextLine();
   System.out.println(foo);
}
```

If i input the string `%ʒŉÛ` I will get the output string `%Ê’Å‰Ã›` When i am doing absolutely zero alterations to the actual string. Can someone help me find a way to avoid this? (BTW avoiding the set of characters `%ʒŉÛ` is very unlikely because its part of an encoding process.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874272/java-scanner-changing-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying the charset:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Do you need to encode on the print statement as well, I'm getting madness coming out; %??�

Comment: I don't think this string is `UTF-8`.

Comment: @RichardTingle probably. Take a look at [this article](http://poeticcode.wordpress.com/2009/01/19/systemout-and-utf8/)